# How to find the missing rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as shown in the image. [image: table structure]

The column `MONTH_NO` should be having months from 1 to 12 for every year. For some years, we missed to load data for some months. I need a query which will fetch the years which doesn't have all the 12 months along with the missing month number.

Please help.

Comment: To whoever is down-voting this, please explain why else the poster cannot improve the question/learn from it.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the explanation could be: 1) Test-data in pictures make it difficult to elaborate a solution, 2) No "this is what I have tried" section.

Comment: Please post the create and insert statements. And show your expected output. See [How to ask a good question](http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html).

Answer (score 1):

For example -

```
with mth
     as (select level as month_no
           from dual
         connect by level <= 12),
     yrs as (select distinct year from rag_month_dim)
select m.year, m.month_no
  from (select year, month_no
          from yrs, mth) m,
       rag_month_dim r
 where m.year = r.year(+)
   and m.month_no = r.month_no(+)
group by m.year, m.month_no
having max(r.month_no) is null
order by year, month_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

post this into an empty query window and adapt to your needs.

MyData contains a "full" year 2013, Sept is missing in 2014 and June and Sept are missing in 2015.

```
DECLARE @OneToTwelve TABLE(Nmbr INT)
INSERT INTO @OneToTwelve VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);

DECLARE @myData TABLE(yearNo INT, MonthNo INT)
INSERT INTO @myData VALUES
 (2013,1),(2013,2),(2013,3),(2013,4),(2013,5),(2013,6),(2013,7),(2013,8),(2013,9),(2013,10),(2013,11),(2013,12)
,(2014,1),(2014,2),(2014,3),(2014,4),(2014,5),(2014,6),(2014,7),(2014,8),(2014,10),(2014,11),(2014,12)
,(2015,1),(2015,2),(2015,3),(2015,4),(2015,5),(2015,7),(2015,8),(2015,10),(2015,11),(2015,12);

WITH AllYears AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT yearNo FROM @myData
)
,AllCombinations AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @OneToTwelve AS months
    CROSS JOIN AllYears
)
SELECT * 
FROM AllCombinations
LEFT JOIN @myData AS md ON AllCombinations.Nmbr =md.MonthNo AND AllCombinations.yearNo=md.yearNo
WHERE md.MonthNo IS NULL
```

Comment: OP is on Oracle not SQL Server.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, Oh yes... Thx for the hint... Maybe the answer helps to elaborate an approach ... The magic word is "Tally Table".

Comment: In Oracle, you simply  need to use the **Analytic function** `MAX() OVER()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select distinct year, m.lev
  from rag_month_dim a
  join
  (
    select level lev
    from dual
    connect by level <= 12
  ) m
  on 1=1
  minus
  select year, month_no
  from rag_month_dim
  order by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (select count (-1) total, year from rag_month_dim group by year) as table
where total < 12.
```

you got a year that doesnt have 12 month data and total month record in your data.